# Jeffrey's prior

Tags: probability, bayesian

I am currently working on a question, however I am a bit confused about which one I need to work out.

Question: Derive Jeffrey's prior $J(\phi)$ when $\theta = e^\phi$ for $f(x|\theta) = \theta e^{-x\theta}$.

So which one do I need to work out, $\pi(\phi)$ or $\pi(\theta)$?